# Bounding $L^6$ norm by $L^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, inequality, lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces

Let $H$ be the completion (in the $L^2$ norm) of the space of divergence-free smooth functions with compact support in some bounded set $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^3$, and $V = H \cap (H^1_0)^3$. I am following a proof of the following lemma:

> If  $u \in L^\infty(0, T; H) \cap L^2(0, T; V)$ then
> $$(u \cdot \nabla)u \in L^{4/3}(0,T; L^{6/5}).$$

I have understand everything aside from somehow bounding the $L^6$ norm by $L^2$. More specifically, let $u \in L^\infty(0, T; H) \cap L^2(0, T; V)$, then for fixed time I would like to prove that
$$\|\nabla u\|_{L^2} \|u\|_{L^2}^{1/2}\|u\|_{L^6}^{1/2} \leq C \|u\|_{H^1}^{3/2}\|u\|_{L^2}^{1/2}.$$
Using the fact that
$$\|u\|_{H^1} = \|u\|_{L^2} + \|\nabla u\|_{L^2}$$
it follows that
$$\|\nabla u\|_{L^2} \|u\|_{L^2}^{1/2}\|u\|_{L^6}^{1/2} \leq \|u\|_{H^1} \|u\|_{H^1}^{1/2} \|u\|_{L^6}^{1/2} = \|u\|_{H^1}^{3/2} \|u\|_{L^6}^{1/2}.$$
However this is where I am stuck, how would I then bound the $L^6$ norm by some multiple of the $L^2$ norm, that is
$$\|u\|_{L^6} \leq C \|u\|_{L^2}?$$

I am thinking that this might follow from the assumption that $\Omega$ is bounded, because then $L^q \subset L^p$ for all $1 \leq p \leq q \leq \infty$. So applying this to $q = 6$, if $\|u\|_{L^6} < \infty$, then that $\|u\|_{L^2} < \infty$ as well. Hence choose $C$ sufficiently large so that $\|u\|_{L^6} \leq C\|u\|_{L^2}$. But since $u$ is arbitrary I feel uneasy about this, as $C$ depends on $u$.

Comment: Where does this inequality you want to prove come from? And is $u$ arbitrary? What is the space?

Comment: @stange I have edited my post to include more details.

Comment: You already received your answer that you should use Sobolev’s inequality, but I’d like to point out that you can’t control a higher $L^p$ norm with a lower one (i.e if $p<q$, then you can’t expect an inequality like $\|f\|_{L^q}\leq C\|f\|_{L^p}$ to hold, where $C$ is independent of $f$). To gain some extra integrability (i.e to be able to put a higher $L^p$ norm on the LHS of your inequality), you need to give up some of your regularity (i.e put some Sobolev norm on the RHS of the inequality). This trade between integrability and regularity is the whole game of Sobolev’s inequalities.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thank you, I am new to Sobolev inequalities so this type of insight is helpful. I wonder if for the proof of the lemma I included in my question whether $C$ being independent of $u$ is really necessary since all we need is finiteness. If so, I assume my proof is salvageable?

Comment: being independent of $u$ is important, because right now, you may be working with just smooth compactly supported functions, so all the Lebesgue and Sobolev norms are finite for trivial reasons. But, the purpose of these estimates is to show that certain function spaces can be included in others, or that certain operators between function spaces are continuous (and also eventually, you’ll end up using a density argument to prove things not just for smooth compactly supported guys). For all of this, it is very important for $C$ to not depend on too many things (certainly not the function $u$).

Comment: @peek-a-boo I see why $C$ being independent of $u$ is important for general inclusions. But to prove the lemma I wanted to show that $\|(u \cdot \nabla)u\|_{L^{6/5}}$ is finite. So by showing $\|(u \cdot \nabla)u\|_{L^{6/5}} \leq c\|u\|_{H^1}^{3/2} \|u\|_{L^2}^{1/2}$ we can achieve this, and so I thought here $C$ doesn't need to be universal. Is this incorrect?

Comment: You’re doing this for a fixed time right? But later you need to show the $L^{4/3}$ in time, so if your $c$ depended on $u$ (really $u(t)$ for a fixed $t\in[0,T]$), then how would you know that the resulting $c(t)$ doesn’t screw things up?

Comment: @peek-a-boo Ah I see now. Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\Omega$ is nice enough, we can use Sobolev's inequality
$$ \Vert u \Vert_{L^6(\Omega)} \leq C \Vert u \Vert_{W^{1,2}(\Omega)}$$
for some constant $C>0$, since
$$ \frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3}.$$
I guess this bound should suffice here. 
EDIT: The inequality was falsely stated as $\Vert u \Vert_{L^6(\Omega)} \leq C \Vert \nabla u \Vert_{L^2(\Omega)}$. As @peek-a-boo pointed out, constant functions are a counterexample to this one.

Comment: Are you using the Gagliardo-Nirenberg-Sobolev inequality? If so, I thought that theorem only applies when the measure space is all of $\mathbb{R}^n$? Also how would we then bound $\|\nabla u\|_{L^2}$ by $\|u\|_{L^2}$?

Comment: There are generalizations on nice enough sets $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^3$, say, open, bounded and $C^1$ boundary. We don't need to bound it by $\Vert u \Vert_{L^2(\Omega)}$, we can simply bound it by $\Vert u \Vert_{H^1(\Omega)}$, which is good enough.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know the name (or have any links/references) for the generalization? It seems like a useful inequality to have.

Comment: You're welcome. You can find these inequalities in chapter 5.6 in Evans' PDE book.

Comment: it’s worth mentioning that the general exponents are that if $\Omega\subset\Bbb{R}^n$ is bounded with (say) $C^1$ boundary, then $W^{1,p}(\Omega)\hookrightarrow L^{p^*}(\Omega)$, where $p^*$ is such that $\frac{1}{p^*}=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{p}$. Here, we have $n=3,p=2$, so $p^*=6$. THis follows from the usual inequality on $\Bbb{R}^n$ coupled with the extension lemma.

Comment: @stange Oh I just noticed this, but your Sobolev inequality is incorrectly written. If $\Omega=\Bbb{R}^3$, then it is true, but if it’s only a bounded open set, then we need to include the full Sobolev norm $C\|u\|_{W^{1,2}(\Omega)}$ on the right (constant functions are a counterexample otherwise).

Comment: @peek-a-boo You're right, thanks. Just edited it.